# JPA Controller Update Function

Tags: angularjs, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-rest

> Error Message: cannot find symbol
>     symbol:   method saveAndFlash(Product)
>     location: variable repository of type ProductRepository

---

I would like to perform an Update with the use of JpaRepository

```
@RestController
public class ProductController {

        @Autowired
        private ProductRepository repository;

        @RequestMapping("/product/{productId}")
        public Product getProduct(@PathVariable long id) {
            return repository.findOne(id);
        }

        @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.PUT, value = "/update")
        public Product updateProduct(@RequestBody Product product, @PathVariable long id) {
            product.setId(id);
            return repository.saveAndFlash(product);
        }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please review [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and add some detail about what errors you're experiencing or what your question is.

Comment: As the error clearly states there is no `saveAndFlash` method.. There is however a `saveAndFlush` method...

Comment: Don't forget to accept\upvote answers that helped you...

Answer (score 0):

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/products")
public class ProductController {

        @Autowired
        private ProductRepository repository;

        @GetMapping("/{id}") // GET /products/1
        public Product get(@PathVariable("id") long id) {
            return repository.findOne(id);
        }

        @PutMapping("/{id}") // PUT /products/1
        public Product update(@RequestBody Product product, @PathVariable("id") long id) {
            product.setId(id);
            return repository.saveAndFlush(product);
        }
}
```